# TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance React/Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, destructuring

I am trying to do a SnapShot verification using Jest for my React App for one of the functional component. Here is the component and test file using Jest

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';
import { useAppState } from 'Shared/store';
...

const Form = () => {

const {customReducer, dispatch} = useAppState();
const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm({});

//custom form methods

return (
<>
   <Form ...>
     ...
   </Form>
   ....
</>
);
export default Form;
```

and my test using Jest

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import Form from '../form';

describe('<Form />', () => {
    test('Snapshot', () => {
    const tree = TestRenderer.create(<Form />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

and i was getting below error 
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tried with Enzyme as well but getting the same error. Spend good time in referring other related questions but couldn't figure out. Thank you.

Comment: do you mock any of hooks you are using in component?

Comment: Hello, I have couple of hooks. useAppState(which uses internally useContext) and useState. I haven't mocked neither of them

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem where Storybook threw `Invalid attempt to destruct non-iterable instance` on a component using hooks (useContext).

The solution was to initiate the context with a default value, `createContext([{}, function() {}])`

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17280#issuecomment-549980239)

Comment: thank you. I ended up creating a mocking the StateProvider(using hooks) with FetchMock from '@react-mock/fetch'. I don't know if it best solution, but with this way, isolated the state from component.
Here is working solution here. 
https://codepen.io/siddhukantipudi/pen/KKKrqpK

Comment: Thanks, while i try it i realized that the thing it's the initialization of the context, if you return an array, you have to init as an array with the values you want in there, 

createContext( [ ] )
createContext( [false, () => {}]),
createContext( [ { }, () => {}])
 . . .

Comment: It cannot be used while using react hooks inside of the stateless functional component